# refactor SQL select statement

Tags: sql, jdbc, sybase

I have a bunch of `select` statements

```
select A, B, C, D into #temp_table from TableA where C>1 and C<10 order by A
select distinct A into #temp_two from #temp_table where B like '%term' 
select E.B from #temp_table E, #temp_two F where F.A = E.A
```

Can the above be combined into one select statement through a series of joins etc without using temp tables? I don't like the idea of using temp tables.

Don't have to show me the exact answer, but just some hints will do.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query would produce the same result:

```
SELECT A1.B 
FROM TableA as A1
     JOIN TableA as A2
         ON A1.A = A2.A 
WHERE A1.B like '%term'
    AND A1.C > 1 
    AND A1.C < 10;
```